# Replace lambda with normal function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Is it possible to replace any lambda function with normal function?

```
 e.g. lst1 = [lambda x:x*i for i in range(5)]
      lst2 = [j(2) for j in lst1]
```

Here can we use normal function in stead of lambda?

If it's possible then please tell how to do the same.

Thanks!

Comment: It is always possible. A lambda is just a simple one-line function. What is confusing you?

Comment: Note that with `[lambda x:x*i for i in range(5)]` you will run into classic [What do (lambda) function closures capture in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python) problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you please convert above example replacing lambda with normal function. I am not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def fun(x, i):
    return x * i

lst1 = [partial(fun, i=i) for i in range(5)]
lst2 = [j(2) for j in lst1]
```

Comment: 2 sec quicker, but i guess this is the answer the OP waits for!

Comment: OP's `lst2` does print `[8, 8, 8, 8, 8]` however because `i` is 4 at the end of the loop but I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: Hey thanks AKS, but output are different. Can we change it have same o/p i.e [8, 8, 8, 8, 8] ? I was not knowing this partial concept. Thanks for that :)

Comment: If you just want `[8, 8, 8, 8, 8]` you could use `[8] * 5`.

Answer (score 1):

yes - lambda is actually "make function"; you will need to give it a name

```
lst1 = [lambda x:x*i for i in range(5)]

def replace_lambda(x):
    return x * x

lst2 = [replace_lambda for i in range(5)]

print lst1
print lst2

for idx, func in enumerate(lst1):
    print func(idx)

for idx, func in enumerate(lst2):
    print func(idx)
```

result:

```
[<function <lambda>>, <function <lambda>>, <function <lambda>>, <function <lambda>>, <function <lambda>>]
[<function replace_lambda>, <function replace_lambda>, <function replace_lambda>, <function replace_lambda>, <function replace_lambda>]
0
1
4
9
16
0
1
4
9
16
```